# cross-referencing a listing item does not work

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, cleveref

I want to cross-reference a listing item. I used the label in the `\lstinputlisting`, but the output shows `??`. Here is the script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\maketitle

\section{Listing}
\lstset{language=Python}\label{ls:example}

\lstinputlisting[language=Python, label=my_listing_label, caption={caption.}]{/home/e/Documents/test_latex/test.py}

\section{Another Section}
We reference~\cref{my_listing_label}
\end{document}
```

Here is the `test.py` content:

```
if x==y:
    print("hi")
```

Here is the output:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Also, I need to add that I want the cross-referencing displayed as listing 1 not as section 1.

Comment: Did you run it twice?

Comment: @Sigur  Yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Load `cleveref` last

Loading `cleveref` last solves this issue.

## Some packages are best loaded after others

Not all packages play nice with one another. Some packages which are best included in the end (in the order I have found they need to be imported) include

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref} % After hyperref
\usepackage{caption}  % After cleveref.
\usepackage{geometry} % Last of all.
```

For a bit more info see the answers to [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/106804).

## A working example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cleveref} % <-- Now loaded last of all. 


\begin{document}
    \title{Test}
    \maketitle

    \section{Listing}
    \lstset{language=Python}\label{ls:example}

    \lstinputlisting[language=Python, label={my_listing_label}, caption={caption.}]{eg.py}

    \section{Another Section}
    We reference~\cref{my_listing_label}
\end{document}
```

[image]